# React+Redux Looking for absolute path after deployed in Apache2 and /var/www/html/MyProject ( ubuntu system )

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router

am using react+redux and Router

in router path index page taking /myproject and other router also taking along with /myproject/xxx/yyyy etc how to resolve this wheras in react npm server if give index path ="/" its working but not in apache2 or any other

this is my code snippet:

```
<Router history={browserHistory}>
<Route name="index" path="/Referral" component={App} />
<Route name="Referral" path="/Referral/details(/:pathParam)" component={UserDetails} />
<Route name="notifications" path="/Referral/notifications" component={Notifications} />
<Route name="report" path="/Referral/report" component={Report} />
<Route name="addpatient" path="/Referral/AddUser" component={AddPatient} />
<Route name="invalidURL" path="*" component={Page404} />
```

this  above code is always looking for path="/Referral/xxx" since when am goto next page and come back  path (previous path) changed to  like http://localhost/Referral//Referral/notifications if u u see path /Referral adding twice . but in npm server which is provided by create-react-app not facing this issue without /Referral/ also working

Comment: i mean project name and index name should be match if i give just local host it wont work if i give /localhost/projectname(path of index name also same as project name ) then its works

Comment: Can you provide a link you use to navigate to the page when you get `Referral//Referral/notifications`? This is most likely caused because of the relative link you used.